# js and css defined in the masterpage does not included in the child page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Hi:
I am new to asp.net,so I meet some problem about the master page.

I define a master page and set some css and js within it:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
    1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server" >
    <title>Master page title</title>
    <script xx.js></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
           <tr>
               <td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Main" runat="server" /></td>
               <td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Footer" runat="server" /></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then my child page:

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
    Footer content.
</asp:content>
```

When I start the child page,I found the xx.js is not included in this page,what is the problem?

Comment: Did you specified the js file path correctly, like this <script src="xx.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ?

Comment: are you able to access the xx.js in master page?

Comment: If you're working in Visual Studio you can drag and drop the JS file from solution explorer into the HTML of your master page and it will create the script tag with the correct path automatically for you.

Comment: Yes,the xx.js in my master page is just a example here,its path is right in my application,and when I check the source code of the child page(the html),I can not find the xx.js,if the path is not right,it will be shown in the source html code,isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xx.js"></script>
</head>
```

This "xx.js" should be in your appl